# django project not working with apache2, working ok with inbuilt web server

Tags: python, django, apache2

I have a django project and working with the in-built webserver. I am trying to move it to apahce and having trouble.Would anyone please be able to help.
My project structure is:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9dLe.jpg)

home/p/prjct
|-- setest
|      `--  wsgi.py
|
|-- manage.py
|-- penve
|
|-- hello
|
|-- tsts

wsgi.py (and other files) are in the folder setest
penve is the virtual environment
hello and tsts are apps.

I have made changes in my apache2.conf and it looks like:

```
DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/p/prjct/setest/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonHome /home/p/prjct/penve
WSGIPythonPath /home/p/prjct

<Directory /home/p/prjct/setest>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>

DocumentRoot /home/p/prjct
Listen 80

AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
```

Am I missing something.
Thanks in advance for help.
sp

Comment: Have you installed en enabled mod_wsgi? `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi` and `sudo a2enmod wsgi`

Comment: Yes that had already been done without any message. And the thing is that the apache2 starts without any message.